# Most efficient Anti-Crack methods

Tags: objective-c, ios, detect, cracking, piracy-prevention

Since cracking is a huge problem I want to go deep into blocking those pirates (I don't even want to mention Cydia Themes, I have recorded a cracking percentage of over 98% on my themes which are all under 1$!!). There are several methods on how to detect cracked apps, but I want to know, which one is the safest and best, and the most difficult to come around for crackers? Here are some of the methods I have looked at: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/36330-iphone-piracy-protection-code-2-another-tutorial.html#post154496

Comment: Is it really a big problem? I was under the impression that piracy is only marginal on iOS, thanks to how locked-down the deployment mechanism is.

Comment: Yes it is a very big problem, over 10% of all idevices are jailbroken most of them just to get apps for free.

Comment: @Thilo: That's the image Apple wants to project, but it's not necessarily the case: http://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/hs5y5/my_ios_app_is_being_pirated_to_the_point_where/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crack protection is a lost cause. Certainly don’t hope for a single “safest and best” anti-crack measure. The protection tricks used on iOS are IMHO mostly heuristics and can be bypassed even without the cracker having to patch the executable. If you insist on doing something against it, mix a few good tricks and hope the cracker is not going to have enough motivation.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is what you want to hear, but IME, it is useless to try to protect against cracking. Using a more sophisticated anti-cracking method only gives the crackers a nicer challenge and they will try to crack it with more enthusiasm. And one of them will succeed.